# ngx-bootstrap Popover dynamic content not working

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use ngx-bootstrap popover in my angular 7 project. I have "bootstrap": "^3.4.0" and "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0" in the package.json file. When I try to include the below code in my html page

```
<div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
      [popover]="content" [popoverTitle]="title">
       Simple binding
     </button>
</div>
```

and the component.ts file

```
export class ImpkpgComponent implements OnInit {

title = 'Welcome word';
content = 'Content1';
```

But I am getting the title displayed in the popover when clicking on the button, not the content.
[image]